# Dynamic functions in jQuery dialog buttons

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following problem.  I'm trying to add dynamic buttons in a modal dialog. But I don´t know,  how I can give the function to each button.

I have the following:

```
     for(i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
          arrButton[i] = { id :  buttons[i].name  , text :  buttons[i].label , click : function(){  buttons[i].onclick  } };
     } 
     $("#divFormulario").dialog
        ({  modal    : true, 
            title    : titulo,
            resizable: false,
            buttons  :  arrButton     
        });
```

For example, if I have the following : `buttons[i].onclick = "functionAlert();`, when I create the button have the click event with `buttons[i].onclick`, but I need the click event with `functionAlert()`.   What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you just put click : function(){  functionAlert();  } ?

Comment: You might as well just use the same object format for your button array as it's required by the dialog, so you could just pass your "buttons" array instead of copying the whole thing into "arrButton".

Comment: If your dynamicaly creating the buttons it would be a good idea to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have an function:

```
function functionAlert() { ...some code... }
```

Instead of passing functions as strings, just do:

```
buttons[i].onclick = functionAlert;
```

Then your loop should be:

```
for(i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
   arrButton[i] = { id :  buttons[i].name  , text :  buttons[i].label , click : buttons[i].onclick };
}
```

Comment: Thank but I tried this, the problem with this is the following message "Microsoft JScript: ..... 'apply'"  the error is produced near of  here "h.click.apply(b.element[0],arguments)"  File of Jquery